# What can you and can't you do with an apple watch that has activation lock

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

My first question is what can you do and what can't you do with an apple watch with an activation lock.

My second question is how can I unpair the watch since the phone is a different location (I'm in South Africa and my brother is in New York with my phone). Is it possible to remove it from iCloud.com

I have to give the watch back to my work since I'm leaving but I can't unpair it. I also don't want to give them a watch with all my personal information on it.

Comment: Why does your work device have your personal files?

Answer (score 1):

**To answer your first question:** There are no limitations to having Activation Lock enabled on your Apple Watch, except for:

> With Activation Lock, your Apple ID and password will be required before anyone can:
>
> - unpair your Apple Watch from your iPhone,
> - or pair and use your Apple Watch with a new iPhone.

*– the above taken from [Apple's support site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205009) –*

But I don't know if those are considered disadvantages.

**As for your second question,** you can unpair the Watch from the iPhone by:

1. Launching the `Settings` app on your Watch
2. Select `General`
3. Tap `Reset`
4. Tap `Erase All Content and Settings`
5. Enter your password, if needed
6. Hit `Continue`

Comment: How would I enter a password without the paired iPhone.

Comment: @user1898829 You can just enter it on the Watch itself, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure but if its an appleID password I doubt it since there are a range of characters in my password and theres no way to type on the watch. Since you said you can't unpair without appleID I'm guessing it is the appleID password. I have no passcode on my watch.

Comment: @user1898829 Give it a try, see what happens. If it is the Apple ID password, we'll go from there.